# AZURE - How to migrate resources from a tenant to another

Tags: azure, migration, client, virtual-machine, subscription

I want to migrate resources (VMs, networks, gateways ...) from a tenant /client with a subscription to another tenant /client with another subscription, with the exact same parameters, how can I do that ? (the move function works only for subscriptions in the same tenant / client, if I download vhd of the VMs I must recreate manually the VMs configuration

Comment: Have you tried using Authoring Templates? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/

Answer (score 3):

The best and most reliable way is through Azure Billing Support. It is free support service and can handle that type of support questions.

Couple of very important things though (hard requirements that cannot be changed):

- target subscription **must be empty**.
- Service Administrator e-mail should be same for both subscriptions
- There should not be co-administrators in both subscriptions for the time of migrating resources
- Some services (i.e. Application Insights) cannot be moved (which services cannot be moved is determined by the support engineers)

Answer (score 3):

For information, I didn't managed to migrate the VMs the way I wanted. I've finally recreate the network infrastructure on the destination tenant, poweredoff the VMs, use azcopy `AzCopy.exe /source:https://<sourceaccountstorage>.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/ /Dest:https://<destaccountstorage>.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/ /sourcekey:<sourceaccountstoragekey> /destkey:<destaccountstoragekey> /pattern:<name of VHD to copy>.vhd` to move the VHDs from the source storage account to the destination storage account (13 min for 130 Gb in westeurope location), and recreate the VMs with powershell with the VHDs `New-AzureRmNetworkInterface, New-AzureRmVMConfig, Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface, Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk and New-AzureRmVM`.

Comment: Hi sdust/Mark,
Any similar way to create classic VM from  VHD ?