# Azure VM from one tenant to another?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to migrate azure ad tenant instance from one tenant to another tenant. Is this is possible ?

Subscription to subscription is possible and migrating between regions is possible.

But not sure on tenant to tenant.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you cannot migrate Azure AD tenant instance from one tenant to another tenant in the Azure portal. Maybe you can do it through Azure Billing Support like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598997/azure-how-to-migrate-resources-from-a-tenant-to-another). Or try another way.

For example, you can make an image from your Azure VM and download the image from Azure. Then upload the image to another tenant. This is a flexible way, but it will take a little longer time. You can follow this document [Download a Linux VHD from Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/download-vhd) to download the VM image which stored as a VHD file.